# Custom comment when sharing feedback doesn't warn of the character limit and simply truncates the text

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, review, character-limit

When reviewing and sharing feedback with a custom comment, the little box thing where I type the comment doesn't warn of the 500-character limit, nor does it give me a countdown of how many characters I have left. What's more, rather than 'erroring' and informing me of the issue when I click enter, it simply truncates the comment to 500 characters. No forewarning, no postwarning, nothing.

Please make it behave like a normal comment and have it provide this information.

(Also, it's annoying that the box covers the answer; that's another issue, but still...)